# skip validation on disabled field in moodle

Tags: validation, moodle

When i click on yes radio button , checkbox should be required and if no then it should not validate the checkbox .Currently it is validating on both condition , i want validtion  only when yes radio button is selected.
Here is image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sFrT.png)

```
    $confirmpreprocedure[] = $mform->createElement('radio', 'preprocedure4', '', get_string('yes','assignsubmission_ebus'), 'yes');
    $confirmpreprocedure[] = $mform->createElement('radio', 'preprocedure4', '', get_string('no','assignsubmission_ebus'), 'no');
    $mform->addGroup($confirmpreprocedure, 'preprocedure4', get_string('preprocedure','assignsubmission_ebus'),array(' '), false);
    $mform->addRule('preprocedure4', null, 'required', null, 'client');

    $mform->disabledIf('preprocedure', 'preprocedure4', 'neq', 'yes');


    $preprocedure   = array();
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox','preprocedure1',get_string('pet','assignsubmission_ebus'),'PET','',array('','PET'));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox','preprocedure2',get_string('contrastct','assignsubmission_ebus'),'Contrast CT','',array('','Contrast CT'));
    $preprocedure[] =  $mform->createElement('advcheckbox','preprocedure3',get_string('ldct','assignsubmission_ebus'),'Low dose CT','',array('', 'Low dose CT'));

    $mform->addGroup($preprocedure,"preprocedure",'if Yes',array('<br>'), false);

    $mform->addRule('preprocedure', null, 'required', null, 'client');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the `disabledIf` line so that it comes after the line where you add the group that you want to disable? I haven't tested it but that's the way it always seems to be done.

Comment: Hello Tony, my disabled if is working fine i just want that when my  field is disable it should not ask for required validation.currently it is asking in both  cases

Comment: Are you sure it's working properly though. Ordinarily I'd expect any validation rules on disabled fields to be disabled too. Try placing the `disabledIf` rule after the `addRule` line.

Comment: Yes tony,i am sure about disabled if, i tried your idea but didnot help.when it is disable validation is still asking field to be entered